# How to use spring acl with spring data rest with out defining custom methods

Tags: spring-security, acl, spring-data-rest

Let's assume I have following repository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "book")
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {
}
```

Spring data rest will publish a few endpoints from his own.
The question is can I wrap POST , PUT /book endpoints with spring security permission evaluations ( Such as: **hasPermission** **WRITE** ) with out defining save method

Comment: I've found documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#security.pre-and-post so, seems I must overide all necessary methods

Answer (score 1):

You can apply security at the HTTP level in your Spring Security config:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    //other config

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, 
           "/book").hasAuthority("MY_PERMISSION");
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, 
           "/book").hasAuthority("MY_PERMISSION");
}
```